# Mat-checkbox is not being checked with the formControl

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I'm trying to mark the mat-checkbox as checked using the formControlName and I set the values to true by default. But the checkbox is not being checked. any ideas what is causing this problem?

here is my code.

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="includeNpw"
        [checked]="IsChecked"
        class="checkbox"
        color="primary"
        fxFlex="0 0 auto">
</mat-checkbox>
```

and the TS file I do this.

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(
private fb: FormBuilder,
private filters: ApplicationListFilterService,
private confService: ConfigurationService,

 ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
  followUp: [false, []],
  rememberFilters: [false, []],
  includeNpw: [true, []],
  includeInFlight: [true, []],
});
```

As you can see the last 2 variables are set to true but nothing happens. I tried to use the [checked]='some variable which is true' but it complains because I'm using the formcontrollerName

Comment: Show your form definition. This code is fine.

Comment: if you use formControlName NOT use [checked], just give value to the formControl true/false (else you're saying to Angular that check the checkbox in two ways)

Comment: @ G. Tranter did get you answer :) 
@Eliseo As you can see above, I already set the includeNpw: [true,[]]. But despite this it is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `[checked]="IsChecked"` inside your `mat-checkboxes` and add `[formGroup]="form"` to the surrounding html tag of your `mat-checkboxes`.

Basically it should look something like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="followUp"></mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="rememberFilters"></mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="includeNpw"></mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="includeInFlight"></mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: I got rid of it, and it is still now showing anything. BTW if I have formControlName = "includeNpw" it is not equal to [formGroup] = "includeNpw"?

Comment: no they are not equal. Can you edit your question to show your whole html?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/arxloyadylp

We have:

```js
  myGroup = this.fb.group({
      followUp: [false, []],
      rememberFilters: [false, []],
      includeNpw: [true, []],
      includeInFlight: [true, []],
    });
```

and

```html
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" 
    [formControlName]="'includeNpw'">
  </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: i have formGroup & formcontrolname. now i can set the last 2 as true. But if i change the value is not going to change as false